# iOS: AmazonDrive URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, amazon-clouddrive

I'm looking for the iOS URL Scheme Amazon Drive.Tried amzndrive:// , acd://..etc. Nothing works out, can anyone provide me the URL scheme please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Drive does not currently support iOS URL Schemas.

I asked the same question in the Amazon support forums and the reply was:

Jamie@Amazon · May 12 at 10:54 PM
Unfortunately, I do not believe that this is available for Drive, but I have passed this on to the team as a feature request.

You probably know you can test the URL scheme out in the Safari app by just entering for example aiv:// as the website name. What's interesting however is that if you enter in a valid URL Schema and then hit cancel, the next valid URL schema you enter WILL NOT WORK.  You have to force close Safari and open it back up again.

Comment: Thanks! @Bruce Seymour